# Why .NET Standard 2 build references many assemblies instead of single netstandard.dll assembly

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

Unlike .NET Standard 1, .NET Standard 2 introduces a single `netstandard.dll` reference assembly.

However, when compiling (with .NET Core SDK 2.2.203) with `dotnet build` we can see that it adds references to many assemblies (113), all under `netstandard.library/2.0.3/build/netstandard2.0/ref/*.dll`. One of these references is `netstandard.dll`.

```
$ grep TargetFramework *.csproj
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
$ dotnet build --verbosity normal | grep -o netstandard.library/2.0.3/build/netstandard2.0/ref | wc -l
113
```

The resulting assembly does contain a single reference to netstandard:

```
$ ikdasm test.exe | grep extern
.assembly extern netstandard
```

The question is why `netstandard.library` NuGet package contains all these other assemblies, and why are they used during build, instead of referencing a single `netstandard.dll`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sadly due to history.

You are right that in theory only `netstandard.dll` is needed to build a .NET Standard library.

However, two things complicate this:

1. .NET Standard 1.0-1.6 libraries used a lot more NuGet packages and thus assemblies. So a .NET Standard 1.6 library (.dll file) may contain references to e.g. `System.Collections.Generic.dll` to be resolvable. Also, the build system needs to know that classes that the 1.6 library expects in this dll is actually the same as the one in `netstandard.dll`.
2. Existing .NET Framework libraries are allowed to be consumed from .NET Standard (and .NET Core) libraries without needing to be recompiled. This means that they also have been built for the `.dll` files that .NET Framework uses - from `mscorlib.dll` to the individual framework dlls.

For both of these, references to assemblies with these names (and versions) are added which contain only type forward declarations. So for example `mscorlib.dll` would contain an empty `System.Object` entry that is marked with "go look for that in `netstandard.dll`".

Comment: It was clear that for a runtime (say .NET Core 2.2) to support existing .NET Framework libraries, it has to contain forwarding assemblies, like mscorlib.dll to whatever implementing assembly. It was not clear why such assemblies are needed during build time. Now, it's clear: I took .net 4 assembly with a single class and single method returning string, and referenced it together with `netstandard2.dll`. It failed because it cannot assign `[mscorlib]String` to `[netstandard]String`. As soon I added reference to netstandard2's `mscorlib.dll` reference assembly, it worked.